# How to run World of Warcraft (WoW)?

Tags: partitioning, windows, wine, games, ntfs

Actualy I'm new with WINE I just need more time to get it, but until this day come I want to play on World of Warcraft on Ubuntu, but the problem it's the folder containing wow is not with windows partition so how to make wine run it.

My Ubuntu is 13.10

disk partition:

-sda2: windows (ntfs)

-sda3: Ubuntu (ext4)

-sda4: documents (ntfs) //wow folder is here.

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WorldofWarcraft) first.

If wou don't want to install WoW again, you can just pass the "Installing World of Warcraft" step.

Comment: I think copy to a ext4 partition is not a necessary step have to do, you can just run WoW in Windows partition (maybe it's a NTFS or FAT32 partition). Sorry I have not enough permission to commit under comrademike's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy WoW over to the ext4 partition in the File Manager. You need to install wine from the Software Center or download the latest version. After it is installed right click on the WoW .exe file and open it with the Wine program loader.

It may not work but give it a try is my advice.

Comment: Thx for the advice but I wanna keep your suggestion as a last option because I prefer to run it from it's current partition